# How to identify 64 bit processor with cat /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit

I have `intel celeron d 3.06ghz processor` . Now I am using `32 bit Ubuntu` and I wish to upgrade to `64 bit Ubuntu` if my `processor` allow. My doubt is  how to identify `64 bit processor` with **cat /proc/cpuinfo**  command.  it shows

clflush size    : 64

Does my processor support `64 bit` OS ?

Comment: See also [How do I know that my CPU supports 64bit operating systems under Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14384/4319)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the lscpu command.

32bit example output:

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    4
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 26
Stepping:              5
CPU MHz:               2260.998
BogoMIPS:              4521.99
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
```

64bit example:

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
CPU(s):                4
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
CPU socket(s):         1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 23
Stepping:              6
CPU MHz:               2327.533
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              6144K
```

Comment: For those who are interested: This is what it shows if you are running a 32bit OS on a 64bit CPU: `Architecture:          i686` / `CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit`

Answer (score 12):

The `flags` section will contain `lm` if you have a Intel 64-/AMD 64-capable CPU. Other 64-bit architectures should have similar flags that you can look for.

Answer (score 5):

To know if the installed Ubuntu is of 32 or 64 bits:

a) `getconf LONG_BIT`

b) `uname -m`

If it shows *i686* or *i386* it means 32 bits. If it shows *x86_64* it means 64 bits.

If the CPU is of 32 bits Ubuntu must be of 32 bits. If the CPU is of 64 bits it can work in 64 or 32 bits. So we can choose: Ubuntu can be of 32 bits or of 64 bits.

To know if the CPU is of 32 or 64 bits:

a) `grep -w lm /proc/cpuinfo`

If we see lm in red is of 64 bits. Otherwise is of 32 bits.

b) `sudo lshw | grep "description: CPU" -A 12 | grep width`

It says clearly what we want to know.

Comment: First part is obsolete. OP says "Now I am using 32 bit Ubuntu".

Comment: `lsb_release -a` works for LSB compatible distros.

Answer (score 0):

```
lscpu
```

Not using cat /proc/cpuinfo , but it will do.

If you, for some reason, really need to use that file, try:

```
grep flags /proc/cpuinfo
```

If you can find a "lm" flag, you are running a 64bit cpu.

Comment: AFAIK uname shows only information about the compiled kernel. Of course you can have a 32bit kernel instaled in 64bit hardware, but not the other way.

Comment: I know, I changed it immediately. Now it should be OK.

Comment: -1: bad karma - you just copied from the other answers.

Comment: Well... I didn't but do your best.